# Is it possible to pass a type and a pointer of that type to a c++ template class using a single parameter of a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to pass a type and a pointer of that type to a c++ template class using a single parameter of a template class?

---

I want to take a pointer to a embedded hardware address (an uart) which has the type `UART_HandleTypeDef` and deduce that type information instead of manually declaring it. Something akin to:

```
template<typename T> class serial{
public:
    T::value_type* uart = T;
};
```

I want to get away from the normal notation which would require me to state the type and then pass a pointer:

```
template<typename T,T* ptr> class c{
public:
  T* _ptr = ptr;
};
```

update:
I forgot to mention: pre C++11 is supported by my compiler. It supports [*some* C++11 features](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1407404265784.htm)

Comment: But basically, C++03? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Here is the [full list](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1407404265784.htm).

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to initialize a data member with a template parameter instead of using the constructor ?

Comment: I'm trying to write some kind of static adapter/decorator for my modbus class. It should accept rs232 and rs485 and these both need uart but only rs485 needs to have pins.

Comment: And what's the problem by using a constructor ? I don't get it.

Comment: The code looks weird to me. If you have a template argument, why do you need a member? And if you do have a member, what's the point of having template argument?

Comment: I'm trying to use compile time polymorphism to get away from a vtable and such. I'm in an embedded environment so removing stuff on the free store is beneficial for me while also removing extra function calls.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @TarickWelling You can use CRTP to implement compile time polymorphism without needing a non type template parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver saw that term before, seems like I indeed am looking for such a solution as having non type parameters is just a big mess in my usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++17, you might have

```
template <auto* ptr> class c
{
public:
    auto _ptr = ptr;
};
```

Before that,

```
template <typename T, T* ptr> class c
{
public:
    T* _ptr = ptr;
};
```

is the way to go.

MACRO can help since C++11

```
#define TEMPLATE_AUTO(...) decltype(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__

c<TEMPLATE_AUTO(my_ptr)> v;
```

Comment: I forgot mention but I can only use a limited subset of C++11. Seems like a great answer otherwise though.

Comment: `TEMPLATE_AUTO` should be `#define TEMPLATE_AUTO(...) decltype(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__` because macros don't understand `<>` surrounding `,`.  With yours, try `template<class T, std::size_t N> std::array<T, N> zeros = {{0}};` and `TEMPLATE_AUTO( &zeros<int, 10> )` -- your macro can explode (depending on how lax your preprocessor is), mine works.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Thanks, improved.